# Server error 500.When installing Ospos onn a local lamp server

Tags: 500-error

I am getting server error 500 when I try to install [Opensourcepos](http://www.opensourceposguide.com/guide/gettingstarted/installation) on a local lamb server on my ubuntu. I am attaching the error output.I will attach a screenshot of changes I made.Kindly help me figure out what is causing the error.It works fine with other PHP files.[Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q6cg.png)

This is the .htaccess file i kept in html folder

```
# redirect to public page
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}public/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# disable directory browsing
# For security reasons, Option all cannot be overridden.
Options +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -
Indexes

# prevent folder listing
IndexIgnore *

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule authz_core_module>
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Require all denied
</Files>

# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files error_log>
Require all denied
</Files>

# prevent access to LICENSE
<Files LICENSE>
Require all denied
</Files>

# prevent access to csv, txt and md files
<FilesMatch "\.(csv|txt|md|yml|json|lock)$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>

# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files error_log>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>

# prevent access to LICENSE
<Files LICENSE>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>

# prevent access to csv, txt and md files
<FilesMatch "\.(csv|txt|md|yml|json|lock)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
```

nano 000-default.conf
and i changed Change the DocumentRoot from /var/www/html to /var/www/html/public.
Its after that the this error comes before that it will show all content in html and html/public is not accessible then also.

Also i have doubt regarding this encryption described I did this a asked in the tutor

```
Now you want to add your encryption key. You can generate a 
CodeIgniter encryption key automatically using the Random Key 
Generator website. Type:

nano config.php

Find the code that says $config['encryption_key'] and add your key. 
Then press Ctrl-x to exit, making sure you save your changes.
```

Answer (score 1):

i know this question is a bit old, but this answer might help another person, i ran into same problem just now, and after i enabled php error display to screen its turns out to be **php-bcmath module error** and after installing and enabling it on my ubuntu 18.04 server the Error 500 disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

A 5XX error will almost certainly leave a log message in your httpd logs. You should track that error message down, the information will lead you to a solution with the aid of your favorite search engine and some research.